# Why is my Java Vertx project not connecting with web project using SockJS?

Tags: java, vert.x, sockjs

My problem comes when I try to implement SockJS on Java Vertx with a simple broadcast message example , I only get the "Welcome to SockJS message!" on the server side, but the frontend and the backend do not seem to be connecting. I am new to Vertx and SockJS, so any help will be very much appreciated.

Here is my **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Push Notifications</title>
    <script src="client.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.io/sockjs-client@1.5.0/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Push Notifications With Vertx</h1>

    <script>

        var sock;

        function openSock() {
        
        sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/myapp');
            sock.onopen = function() {
                sock.onopen = function() {
                    console.log('open');
                   };

                   sock.onmessage = function(e) {
                    console.log('message', e.data);
                   };

                   sock.onevent = function(event, message) {
                    console.log('event: %o, message:%o', event, message);
                    return true; // in order to signal that the message has been processed
                   };
               
                   sock.onerror = function(e) {
                    console.error(e);
                }

                   sock.onunhandled = function(json) {
                    console.log('this message has no address:', json);
                   };

                   sock.onclose = function() {
                    console.log('close');
                   };
           
           sock.send('test');
           
        }
    }
    openSock();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my **MainVerticle.java**

```
package com.bcm.vertxmvn;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.SockJSHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.SockJSHandlerOptions;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainVerticle.class);

    @Override
    public void start() {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        SockJSHandlerOptions options = new SockJSHandlerOptions()
                .setHeartbeatInterval(2000);

        SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx, options);

        router.mountSubRouter("/myapp", sockJSHandler.socketHandler(sockJSSocket -> {

            // Just echo the data back
            sockJSSocket.handler(sockJSSocket::write);

        }));
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(8080);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I just copied your code, and it worked without any problems. Could you further elaborate how you check your software? I started the server, opened the index.html and had a look into the console output in my browsers development tools. When I end the server, an additional close message appears in the console output. Seem good to me.

Comment: I use intellij idea to run a Main class that deploys my MainVerticle.java, when I check on port 8080 (localhost:8080) it displays "welcome to sockjs!" But when I send a message from my web project using "sock.send()" that message is not displayed on my server (I am also using web server for chrome on my web project)

Comment: Excuse my late response. So, is there some code missing then? I don't see any line of code in your server that could print anything. But on the console.log in the browser I see that your code is working. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I figured the reason because this was not working is because I had two servers, now I have stopped using web server for chrome and it worked for a while. I managed to serve my web project from my java vertx server using StaticHandler, but now I dont get any messages from console whatsoever. (I need to have a server because I am trying to implement Push Notificatios on my app and that requires having a Service Worker and service workers require a server to work )